# Python PIL For Loop to work with Multi-image TIFF

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

Each tiff file has 4 images in it. I do not wish to extract and save them if possible, I would just like to use a for loop to look at each of them. (Like look at the pixel [0,0] )and depending on what color it is in all 4 I will do something accordingly.

Is this possible using PIL? 
If not what should I use.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the "seek" method of a PIL image to have access to the different pages of a tif (or frames of an animated gif).

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('multipage.tif')

for i in range(4):
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        print img.getpixel( (0, 0))
    except EOFError:
        # Not enough frames in img
        break
```

Comment: FYI, This solution worked >1000x faster to later access the individual pixels  in a frame (0.0002sec) than the pims library (0.348093sec).  pims is supposedly based on tiffile.py.  PIL was still slower than opencv (6.7e-05sec), but opencv doesn't support multi-page tiffs (tiff stacks).

Comment: @user391339 FYI: OpenCV now supports multi-page tiffs with imreadmulti (link below).

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga4dd47c9ae3d55cc42286cff005825e31

Answer (score 36):

Rather than looping until an `EOFError`, one can iterate over the image pages using [`PIL.ImageSequence`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#using-the-imagesequence-iterator-class) (which effectively is equivalent as seen on the [source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/0730e88b15b9ba8df6576e99e23199e12250ab12/PIL/ImageSequence.py#L37-L42)).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

im = Image.open("multipage.tif")

for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(im)):
    page.save("page%d.png" % i)
```

Answer (score 7):

Had to do the same thing today,

I followed @stochastic_zeitgeist's code, with an improvement (don't do manual loop to read per-pixel) to speed thing up.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def read_tiff(path):
    """
    path - Path to the multipage-tiff file
    """
    img = Image.open(path)
    images = []
    for i in range(img.n_frames):
        img.seek(i)
        images.append(np.array(img))
    return np.array(images)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method that reads a multipage tiff and returns the images as a numpy array

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def read_tiff(path, n_images):
    """
    path - Path to the multipage-tiff file
    n_images - Number of pages in the tiff file
    """
    img = Image.open(path)
    images = []
    for i in range(n_images):
        try:
            img.seek(i)
            slice_ = np.zeros((img.height, img.width))
            for j in range(slice_.shape[0]):
                for k in range(slice_.shape[1]):
                    slice_[j,k] = img.getpixel((j, k))

            images.append(slice_)

        except EOFError:
            # Not enough frames in img
            break

    return np.array(images)
```

Comment: PIL/Pillow stores and refers to images using [col,row] whereas numpy uses [row,col]. I got the above code to work by changing the height and width locations, i.e. ``slice_ = np.zeros((img.width, img.height))``

Comment: The number of frames within TIFF file is stored within `n_frames` property. Also, to convert them into numpy array you don't need to copy each individual pixel - it's as easy as `numpy.array(image)` where `image` is PIL image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers on this thread I wrote this python module for reading and operating on multipage tiff files: https://github.com/mpascucci/multipagetiff

It also allows to color-code the image stack "depth-wise" and make z-projections.

Hope it can help