# Working with tiled, pyramid tiff images in PIL - Python 2.7

Tags: python, tiff, python-imaging-library

I have some tiff images that have between 7-8 levels. These were generated using vips. I have tried the iteration listed at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602525/python-pil-for-loop-to-work-with-multi-image-tiff). I've also tried this:

```
im = Image.open("E:\\tiled_pyr.tif")
for i in range(7):
    try:
        im.seek(i)
        print im.size[0]
        print im.size[1]
    except EOFError:
        # Not enough frames in im
        break
```

However, when I begin iterating through, I get this error:

```
IOError: decoder tiff_adobe_deflate not available
```

What I'm trying to do is crop the ptif at its highest resolution or highest level and then run some analysis on that crop.

Is this possible with PIL? Do I need something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The libvips Python binding pyvips now works on Windows, so you can do:

```
import pyvips

# this will open the highest resolution layer
image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("somefile.tif")

# crop out an area
area = image.crop(x, y, w, h)

# ... do what you like
print('average pixel value of crop is', area.avg())
```

See

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvips