# Convert PDF file to multipage image

Tags: python, image, pdf, pymupdf

I'm trying to convert a multipage PDF file to image with PyMuPDF:

```
pdffile = "input.pdf"
doc = fitz.open(pdffile)
page = doc.loadPage()  # number of page
pix = page.getPixmap()
output = "output.tif"
pix.writePNG(output)
```

But I need to convert all the pages of the PDF file to a single image in multi-page tiff, when I give the page argument a page range, it just takes one page, does anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 7):

```
import fitz
from PIL import Image

input_pdf = "input.pdf"
output_name = "output.tif"
compression = 'zip'  # "zip", "lzw", "group4" - need binarized image...

zoom = 2 # to increase the resolution
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)

doc = fitz.open(input_pdf)
image_list = []
for page in doc:
    pix = page.getPixmap(matrix = mat)
    img = Image.frombytes("RGB", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)
    image_list.append(img)
    
if image_list:
    image_list[0].save(
        output_name,
        save_all=True,
        append_images=image_list[1:],
        compression=compression,
        dpi=(300, 300),
    )
```

Comment: A [multi-page tiff](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-multipage-tif-28815.html) per document is needed. There seems to be some kind of [support, at least for reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18658742/1136400),

Answer (score 4):

When you want to convert all pages of the PDFs, you need a for loop. Also, when you call `.getPixmap()`, you need properties like `matrix = mat` to basically increase your resolution. Here is the code snippet (not sure if this is what you wanted but this will convert all PDFs to images):

```
doc = fitz.open(pdf_file)
zoom = 2 # to increase the resolution
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)
noOfPages = doc.pageCount
image_folder = '/path/to/where/to/save/your/images'

for pageNo in range(noOfPages):
    page = doc.loadPage(pageNo) #number of page
    pix = page.getPixmap(matrix = mat)
    
    output = image_folder + str(pageNo) + '.jpg' # you could change image format accordingly
    pix.writePNG(output)
    print('Converting PDFs to Image ... ' + output)
    # do your things afterwards
```

For resolution, [here is a good example](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/181) from Github to demo what it means and how it's used for your case if needed.

Comment: A [multi-page tiff](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-multipage-tif-28815.html) per document is needed. There seems to be some kind of [support, at least for reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18658742/1136400),

Answer (score 1):

```
import fitz    
pdffile = "input.pdf"
doc = fitz.open(pdffile)
i = 0
for page in doc:
    i += 1
    pix = page.getPixmap()
    output = "output_" + str(i) + ".tif"
    pix.save(output)
```

Comment: Won't this just write the first, overwrite with the second ... and finally overwrite with the last page from the PDF?

Comment: You're right, it would, I'll add a counter to avoid that.

Comment: That will result in multiple files per document, not a multi-page tiff. See my comment on the other answers. [multipage-tiff](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-multipage-tif-28815.html) No idea if doable with python, reading such seems implemented though.

Comment: In that case you can merge the files after they are converted.

Answer (score 1):

PyMuPDF supports a limited set of image types for output. TIFF is **not** among them.

However, there is an easy way to interface with Pillow, which supports multiframe TIFF output.